# Finding top elements of a map using Heap

Tags: c++

I have a `unordered_hashmap` that maps a string (say personName or SSN) to a `struct` `Attributes` that has many attributes of that person including `annualIncome`. There are many such hash maps corresponding to different organizations such as `mapOrganizationA`, `mapOrganizationB` etc. I need to find the people (with attributes) with the top-k annual incomes. I was thinking  of using a min-heap with k-nodes (with the minimum salary as root), so that I can scan the maps one by one, of the current element has income more than the root of the min-heap, the root can be updated. Is this the right approach to get top-k from different maps? Is there a  `min-heap` datastucture in STL I can make use of.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`make_heap`, `push_heap`, `pop_heap`, `sort_heap`, `is_heap`](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/make_heap.html) to treat any non-associative container (or sequence, really) as a heap.

That would not fit you map nicely, but I assume nothing would prevent you from storing the values (or pointers/references to those) inside, say, a list for this purpose?

Also, perhaps look at **[Boost.MultiIndex](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_34_1/libs/multi_index/doc/tutorial/techniques.html)** which is a library precisely focused on providing multiple (efficient!) indexes on the same data